# Configure Windows Server 2008 R2 not to allow remote control for an admin users

Tags: remote-control, windows-server

Let's say we have some users that are administrator of the system but we don't want them to remote control to the server.

How can we do that?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/598278/how-to-disable-rdp-access-for-administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Limit users who can log in using Remote Desktop

By default, all Administrators can log in to Remote Desktop. You can remove all administrative access via RDP and only allow user accounts requiring RDP service.

1. Click Start-->Programs-->Administrative Tools-->Local Security Policy
2. Under Local Policies-->User Rights Assignment, go to "Allow logon through Terminal Services." Or “Allow logon through Remote Desktop Services”
3. Remove the Administrators group and leave the Remote Desktop Users group.
4. Use the System control panel to add users to the Remote Desktop Users group.
5. Run `GPUPDATE /FORCE` for the changes to apply.

[image]